# Get preprocessor constant value using clang

Tags: c, clang

I use clang engine to parse C code. I know how to check text under cursor is preprocessor directive or not. But how to get preprocessor constant value under cursor?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <clang-c/Index.h>

#define TEST "test"

int main()
{
    char *source_filename = "/home/user1/projects/prep/prep.c";
    CXIndex index;
    CXTranslationUnit tu;
    CXFile file;
    CXSourceLocation loc;
    CXCursor cursor;

    index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
    tu = clang_createTranslationUnitFromSourceFile(index, source_filename,
            0, NULL, 0, NULL);
    file = clang_getFile(tu, source_filename);
    loc = clang_getLocation(tu, file, 4, 9);
    cursor = clang_getCursor(tu, loc);

    if (clang_isPreprocessing(cursor.kind)) {
        /* How to get TEST constant value? */
    }

    clang_disposeTranslationUnit(tu);
    clang_disposeIndex(index);
}
```

One more question. Should I free variables of CXFile, CXSourceLocation, CXCursor types after work. I can't find appropriate `clang_dispose` functions for them.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I write small program for Vim plugin which will show variable type (and preprocessor constant value if I understand how) for word under cursor in status line. I never heard about clangd, honestly, I start to read clang docs only today. So I will try to know more about clangd.